# Error when debugging android app in Flutter VScode ('mainMergedManifest')

Tags: android, flutter

Trying to run a Flutter app on an android device returns the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File '<project-directory-path>\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist
```

How do I get rid of this error?